# How to look at a previous pytest results output in Pycharm?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, pytest

I am running a long Pytest folder, with hundreds of tests.

Some of them fail.

When I fix one, I want to run it, and still have the previous long run results available. What currently happens is Pycharm only shows the last run results.

How can I show the results of a previous pytest run in Pycharm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to extract this from the Jetbrains document. Hope this could help to view the history of test results:

> Open the list of internally saved results of test sessions. Each
> item is supplied with the name of the run configuration and a time
> stamp.
>
> To view the results of a testing session from the PyCharm history,
> select the item with the suitable run configuration and time stamp.
> The loaded test results are shown in a new tab, and the name of the
> corresponding run configuration is displayed in the title bar.

[Reference to the document](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/test-runner-tab.html#testingToolbar)

Comment: thanks! Just how to `Open the list of internally saved results of test sessions`?

Comment: @Gulzar np.. in the test toolbar it should appear there as per the reference link I've provided. I haven't personally tested this. Let me know if that works?